# Unused variables from superclass

Tags: java, constructor, initializing

```
class ABC {
    private int[] variable;
    public int[] getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
    public ABC() {
        variable = new int[123456];
    }
}

class DEF extends ABC {
    public int[] getVariable() {
        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

`variable` is used in `ABC`, but completely unused and needless in `DEF`. But I can't see any proper way to prevent creating this big array in `DEF`, because always some constructor of superclass has to be executed.
I see only one, inelegant way: new, "fake" constructor for ABC:

```
protected ABC(boolean whatever) {}
```

Then in `DEF` I can write:

```
public DEF() {
    super(true);
}
```

and it works - `variable` isn't initialized.

But, my question is - can I solve this more properly?

Maybe if variable is unused, compiler automatically deletes her? It's quite often situation, when such feature could be useful.

Comment: Interesting question. as `variable` is marked _private_ in ABC and the getter is overridden, there is absolutely no way for DEF to access it. I wonder also if the compiler is able to delete it in the optimization process.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter It may also have to detect whether it's used via reflection, which could be a lot more difficult / impossible.

Comment: Yeah ... reflection ... I always forget about that. It takes all the fun out of Java programming :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure `DEF` needs to extend `ABC` - I mean, is a `DEF` logically a `ABC`? Inheritance is powerful but needs to be used with caution.

In your case, I'd rather have:

```
public interface WithVariable {
  int[] getVariable();
}
```

And have both `ABC` and `DEF` implementing `WithVariable`. This way constructing a `ABC` object will initialise the needed variable, and constructing a `DEF` object won't do anything, but they'll both reply to the same message (`getVariable()`).

Comment: +1 very good answer but if `DEF` is `ABC`, question remains unanswered

Comment: I think the proper way to solve problem the OP asked is to use an `interface`, as the fact you're not using `variable` original value populated in the constructor is a smell that `DEF` is not really a `ABC`.

Comment: Yes, I want DEF to be ABC. Sorry, I don't know how to insert bigger amount of code: http://wklej.org/id/1128907/

Comment: @KrzysztofStanisławek if that's the case, make the `Log` class abstract or create a `Log` interface. Also, with your current design, `BetterLog` has two `ArrayList<Entry> entryList;`, one from super class and another that hides the field from super class.

Comment: I agree with Luiggi - from your code it really seems to me that you should have an `interface`. `BetterLog` doesn't reuse current functionality of `Log`, you're also reassigning the `protected` variable. Extending `Log.Entry` is fine, but `BetterLog` and `Log` should implement the same interface IMHO.